# Can a one variable function $g(x)=0$ be a continous curve?

Tags: calculus, optimization, graphing-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I am studying the geometric interpretation of **sequential linear programming method.**

We consider the one variable problem which is illustrated in the book Engineering Optimization
Theory and Practice by Singiresu S. Rao:

Minimize $$f(x) = c_1 x$$ subject to $$g(x) \le 0,$$ where $c_1$ is a constant and $g(x)$ is a non linear function of $x$.

The problem is with the following picture :
[image]

I dont understand on what plane they are plotting the curves. How the curve which looks like parabola can represented by the equation $g(x)=0$. I thought that $g(x)=0$ may not look like a continous non linear curve. How $g(x)<0$ is the region above parabola and $g(x)>0$ is below? Please someone help.